# Mern app where i have to save profile pictures of users

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, amazon-web-services

Im creating a `mern` app where i have to save profile pictures of users.
My question has **3** parts:

**1**)What is the best file hosting service (image hosting) to save images in database how to configure it with mern.Im using `mongodb`.

**2**)We are planning to deploy the app on `aws` server later. Should i save it on `aws`.If yes how(Procedure) and how much it will cost as we are on tight budget right now and not planning to deploy for atleast 5 months.

**3**)Is there any other cost efficient way ,if yes kindly share it with procedure as im new to web programming.

Comment: You want a file hosting service, I believe aws has a free one. In your database, you just save the url of the file.

Comment: can i kow the procedure as im new to this.Also if later we deploying to to aws will it effect my app somehow.

Answer (score 1):

Images are usually not persisted in a database itself, due to their large size once system gets bigger, but on file system (you can save them into local folder for development purposes, and on AWS for production purposes, for instance). In the database you can keep image data like image file system path, size in pixels etc.